# How to flip a stack of images on it's side

Tags: windows, image, image-processing

I have a stack of 400 images, each with dimensions of 400*400 pixels that i need to flip onto it's side so that the left-most column of each image in the old stack becomes the top image in the new stack, the second columns become the second image, and so on. I am using windows, but there are few other restrictions, as i can use imagej to save the stack in any reasonable format, including gif, tif, and a set of sequentially named non-layered images. Additionally, i only need to do this twice, so a workaround is fine.

Comment: What programming language should this problem be solved in?

Comment: I know c/c++, but any language is fine if a complete script is given. A solution involving manual steps in existing computer programs would also be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself in imagej (posibly the "fiji" version only) using Image>stacks>reslice Which does exactly what i want.